# How to horizontally scroll through divs with a linear gradient effect?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to horizontally scroll through items (the blue boxes) while the gradient effect of the container (the white fade effect on the ends) only applies to items at the beginning and end of the scroll. Below is the closest I've gotten so far. But right now the gradient seems baked into the items as I scroll through them. But if I don't wrap the items under the container, the gradient has no effect on the items themselves.  How can I make it so that the gradient effect is in one position, and I can stroll through my items so that only items that scroll past the gradient will have the effect like in normal navigation?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "item"></div>
   <div class = "item"></div>
   <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
   <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background-attachment: fixed;`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "item"></div>
   <div class = "item"></div>
   <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
   <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another point on your Linear CSS to 'pull' the opacity further out like this:

`background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);`

You will have to play with the two middle colour stops to get it to match your idea. You could also apply linear gradients to just the first and last DIV.